# HIghchart : Animation issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, highcharts

i use Highchart in my application which developed in asp.net MVC.
I use Line chart in my application i use this chart in my dashboard page in that page already more than 20 controls render so in that case chart display but it can't animated.
so tell me how to resolve this?

Comment: In the question add your js for highcharts so that any user can at least debug the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope there might be a conflict in js namespace, try loading the highchart js file at the end of body and initialize the chart on window.onload